# Keyboard shortcut for "close tab" in Firefox

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, web-browser

In other OSes, I've used CTRL+W (or COMMAND+W on Mac OS) to close the current tab in Firefox and other web browsers. Of course, if there is only one tab open, then the window is closed.

But in Elementary OS, that keyboard shortcut tries to close the window, regardless of how many tabs are open. I'm currently having to use the mouse to close tabs, which is a pain!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you didn't customize anything? I've always been using ctrl+w. I can use it in Firefox, Chromium and Epiphany. 
Maybe try a fresh install in a virtual machine to compare.

Comment: Hmm… actually, you might be on to something there, now I come to think about it some more! I suspect you're right, but I will check and let you know. I've got bigger problems with it right now, so it may be a few days! Thanks though :)